# Cross-posting okay from SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There's a [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/1495491/86708) which is on-topic here, and has some answers. Normally, I'd recommend the OP to delete and repost here, but this question has existing answers that would be lost.

Is there a good way to handle this? Would a cross-post be okay if it had a link to the original answer?

Comment: Raise a mod flag and ask for migration. Only mods can move questions along unlisted migration paths.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl That's a good point. I hadn't even thought about migration as an option. I guess I'll leave it to the OP to ask for migration, since its on topic where it is, and isn't guaranteed to get better answers elsewhere.

Comment: You have to raise a mod flag on the origin site for the mods to do the site migration.  They have to be willing to do the migration.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl no, please don't! We do not migrate away things that are on topic and if that question is on topic on [su[, then it should stay there. jpaugh, could you clarify what you see as the problem? If the question has been answered, then SU has a nice new question. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do? Is it just that you think that would be a useful question for us too? In that case, just as it yourself and answer it. That would be great!

Comment: @terdon I think OP would say that the question would be better on-topic on AU, that's why he asked here

Comment: @terdon I went off under the assumption that it was off-topic there. I'm not very active on SU, so I'm not sure where the line goes.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl ah, no, Linux is perfectly on topic on SU. That's the only reason I have any rep there! :)

Comment: @damadam well, that's a bit complicated. Things are either on topic or off topic, they can't really be "more on topic". So while you could argue that the question would get better answers here (it might), that's not because it is more on topic. More importantly, if people think the question is useful, and can reproduce it on their machines, by all means ask it here!

Comment: @terdon I prefer to answer, search for and ask questions on the most specific SE site that applies. Ask Ubuntu (or even the Unix SE) are more specific than SU, although it is on-topic for all three. The OP might get an answer on any of these sites, but I wanted to be able to 1) recommend askubuntu.com without recommending cross-posting, and 2) introduce the OP to our community process for discussing complicated issues, and 3) get more eyes on the post, since (IMO) it will otherwise be less likely to get answered well.

Comment: Lord! Technically, it's on topic on [so], since `pip` is a programming tool. Nevermind that, lol.

Comment: Related: [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) (by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9))

Comment: @EliahKagan Noted. I suppose I've been overzealous.

Comment: @jpaugh To clarify, I commented that because it's an important post and related to the topic, which addresses some of what's been raised here and which will be of interest to people who find this question by searching. I didn't mean it as criticism, and certainly not as admonition. The zeal that leads one to inquire on meta about how to proceed in an uncertain situation is the right amount (and quality) of zeal.

Comment: @jpaugh nothing wrong with that! If you feel the dupe that Kulfy suggested doesn't answer your question, please edit the details from your comment (the 3 concern you raised) and we can answer each of them. I wasn't trying to be difficult or berate you or anything, I honestly didn't understand what problem you perceived. Now I do! :)

Comment: @terdon, Thanks! I think the dupe is on-target, although the comments here generated more targeted, useful advice.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanksl